# Hide URL path from address bar and access it from site only

Tags: laravel, .htaccess, url, redirect

I want to restrict my visitor from accessing my site's sub-pages with URL. They can only access the sub-pages from the website by clicking on a link.

Suppose, for access the user profile page the link is

```
www.example.com/user/2/profile
```

And there is a button with this link for visiting the user profile page.

So, when a user clicks on the button it will be redirected to that URL but if someone directly accesses this URL it will show an error or redirected to the home page.

Or, the URL will be hidden like

```
www.example.com/#
```

In a word, no one access webpages by directly hitting the URL instead of the index page.

Is it possible to do it?

My website is on Laravel.

Comment: _"Is it possible to do it?"_ - not on this level, no. You'd need to use a _session_ for that. In there you can record whether the user visited specific pages, so you can then decide whether to allow or deny access to another page based on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it accessible from your site only you can check the `Referer` HTTP request header. This is empty on direct requests and set to the *referring* URL otherwise (ie. the page on which the link was *clicked*).

However, this is unreliable. Users can configure their browser to not send a `Referer` header (so these users would be blocked). Search engine bots do not send a `Referer` header (if that is a concern). And it is trivial for a mischievous user to *fake* the `Referer` to gain access.

For example, at the top of your root `.htaccess` file (before the Laravel directives) you could do something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https?://(www\.)?example\.com/
RewriteRule ^user/2/profile$ - [F]
```

The above will serve a 403 Forbidden for any request to `/user/2/profile` where the `Referer` HTTP request header does not start `https://www.example.com/` (including `http` and non-www).

> So, when a user clicks on the button it will be redirected to that URL

To clarify, the link the user clicks must be an "ordinary" link that causes the browser to make another HTTP request for the new URL, otherwise a `Referer` will not be generated.

> Hide URL path from address bar

You can't realistically do that.